# Can the soldiers upon this wall successfully withstand this enemy army?

Tags: magic, warfare, architecture, strategy

Edit 7

I'm looking at walls and armies lately and was wondering how to have them built/organized for a fantasy setting. The wall is like the Great wall of China It has influential and powerful magic but not used often, only in battle. There are magical creatures. . .

This wall is protecting a border that is two miles wide. The wall is twenty-five feet tall, seven feet deep, and twelve feet thick made from granite. Turrets (50) are spaced evenly at 52.8 feet and have signal fires drenched in a controlled oil ready to be lit, along with a ballista for flying/really tough enemies. The wall and army is to keep out the following:

Attackers:

- Feral Elves: have claws and teeth/muzzle but use weapons. Near human-intelligence. Able to work together, make primitive armor and use other animals, such as Vargr, as steeds along with chimera and drakes. Senses are 1 1/2 times that of a human. Can use magic but not as powerful as a humans.
- Vargr: 6 feet tall, 14 feet long. Wolf-like body with bear strength. Used as mounts by the elves and armored with leather.
- Demons: wolf level intelligence. Seven feet tall and the strength of two men. Fight with horns, teeth, and their claws. Immune to magic.
- Goblins: ape-intelligence. Small and great climbers. Able to weld weapons. Very swift but not good endurance.
- Drakes: flying with length ranged from 5-20 feet long. Shoot plumes of fire. Scales will hold back most arrows, but not crossbows. Don't like to fly over 50 feet off the ground and won't go higher than 75.
- Chimera: huge (20-35 feet long, 13 feet tall)with wolf/dolphin-level intelligence. Skin has thickness of a rhino but grace of a cat and is able tow withstand bows at close-range. Breath fire in mushroom clouds. Able to break rock with their horns when they charge. Semi-immune to magic (five fireballs will be like scratching it. Lightning works better.)
- Wild Cats: ten feet long leopard like creatures. Pack hunters and stalkers.
- Wyrms: cow-level of intelligence. Near endless hunger. 20 feet long and three feet tall and thick arrow-proof scales. Blind but have great hearing and smell.
- Giant wasps:flying and about a foot long. Hive mentality. Sting causes paralyzing for about three hours but can't get through plate armor. never go higher than 30 feet high
- Vultat; 6-9 feet long, large wings and are nocturnal. If bitten, they leave bacteria in the wound, like a Komodo dragon. Work together in pairs of 3-5.
- Their goal is to break through the wall and cause havoc in the country behind it. For this question we will assume that the only way through is the pass.

Defenders:

- 100 knights with full steel battle armor (everything is steel)
- 400 normal soldiers that can also act as archers. Equipment: spear, shield and a sword. They are the main force. Mainly chain mail armor except for hands, helmets, shin guards, and breastplate. Same goes for pike men.
- 120 pike men that use crossbows at a distance
- 50 wizards that can do the following: 
  throw fireballs up to a hundred feet and has a minute recharge. Lightning is stronger but takes three minutes for recharge. Can charge arrows and projectiles with lightning for a shock but can also throw "chain lighting", were it bounces from person to person. 
  Can make the ground tremor in a mini-earthquake. They can also summon 5-11 meter high tornadoes (the taller=smaller diameter) that'll last for five minutes. Two wizards could combine some fireballs and a tornado and create a fire-tornado.
- Food is not a problem in this scenario and they get supplies every week and a half.

Terrain: relatively flat, a few hills, mountains on either side of the pass, a small (4 feet deep, 9 feet wide) trench in front of the wall. Thought that the soldiers would do that.

**Now, using these statistics, would the defenders be able to withstand the enemies if they are attacked once a week (for four weeks) and what changes would need to be made if not?**

Comment: Once a week for how long? If its forever, and your defenders never get reinforcements they will be worn down no matter what.

Comment: I also have to add that your title and question does not relate to each other, your header of your question is how to build a wall, but your body of the question asks for if your army can withstand attacks for weeks.

Comment: Notice that at  52.8 feet distance (less than 20 meters, I think) by the time you light a fire a horn or the like would have already sent the message.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  I know this might not make sense, but you've provided us with very little of the info we need to answer a question like this. Everything from what's the carbon content and thickness of the steel to how many arrows to kill a drake and a thousand more.  The analysis burden is enormous - and too broad.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: The presence of flying units kind of makes the concept of a wall obsolete.

Comment: Please clarify **why** each creature try to cross the wall? Just hungry? Do they eat each other? Some kind of The Call? Desire to eat people on the wall or to cross it and go to the country? Desire to ground the wall ignoring people? Each option leads to different creature tactics and threats wich guard should respond.

Comment: The numbers on both sides are far too small to overcome chance events, weather, and good/bad leadership. You can have any outcome you like.

Comment: @Hankrecords I was wondering what "dolphin intelligence, able to weld weapons was" -- because I thought that would be a.k.a. "human" intelligence, perhaps a little more fun-loving.

Comment: It seems like any attackers that can mount a drake should just fly over the wall and attack the undefended countryside behind it. Why would they bother attacking the defenders at their strongest point?

Comment: well, that's why the defenders have the tornadoes and the ballistas

Comment: This has been edited and put in the VTR queue, but it's not a worldbuilding question.  It's a storybuilding question (off-topic).  If you want the defenders to win, let them win.  History is full of group A fights group B and in one case A wins and in another B wins.  Everything from weather to luck to divine intervention has tipped the scales.  In other words, unless one group *obviously* outclasses the other, whether or not one will win is entirely up to you, the story teller. As I've thought about this more, you can't judge military outcomes in real life, we can't do it for fiction, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All attackers could be divided to three major groups:

- Ground units without climbing ability and intelligence less than human. (Vargr, Demons, Chimera, Wild Cats, Wyrms). They can't overcome the wall and could be cleaned at free time, after dinner.
- Flying creatures. (Drakes, Giant wasps, Vultat) They just ignoring the wall but incredibly vulnerable to tornados. It's depends on what their goal and how fast they are.
- Feral Elves. Huma-like creatures could invent some tricks.

  - Siege tower is one of them but useless due to tornadoes
  - Access ladders and grapnels with rope is a good one
  - False attacks, night attacks and many other siege tricks
  - Own magic if applicable
  - etc

So your question could be reduced to another one ***How smart and well organised are elves?***

Answer (score 2):

The humans would have a better chance of defending their wall if it **didn't** look like the Great Wall of China.

Have a look at a star-shaped [citadel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citadel). The form enables defenders to shoot at any approaching enemy from at least 2 different points of the wall. Unfold it and you get a zig-zag line that enables more defenders to shoot at a concentrated ground attack.

The citadel shape also enables defenders to shoot at enemies climbing their own wall (an advantage you do not have on a straight wall), but they would need lanterns on the outside of the wall to see them at night. If you hang a lantern really close to the wall, climbers are easily spottet by the long shadows they cast.

Next is communication and specialization. They need different signals for different types of enemies like horns for flying creatures and drums for groun-based enemies. Every soldier must be well trained and know exactly what his task is in an attack.

And don't forget specialized weapons against flying creatures. A manticore might be a fearsome enemy, but throw a net over it to prevent it from flying and the enraged creature will wreak havoc among it's own allies.